# Reading numbers into array and printing off in reverse in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to open a file using command line arguments and read the numbers I have in my 'testdata' file in reverse  The numbers in the test data file consist of:

```
2
20
200
2000
20000
-2
-20
-200
-20000.
```

Here is the code I have written so far.  The file prints out, obviously not in reverse.  I'm assuming I'm just missing a for loop in here somewhere.  I'm also considering that maybe I should be using `fscanf` instead of `fgets`.  Any input is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUMS 1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Int a, n;
    char buf[MAX_NUMS];
    Int array[MAX_NUMS];
    file *pt;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage %s <files..>\n");
    }

    if ((pt = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open %s for reading.\n", argv[1]);
        Return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, MAX_NUMS, pt) != NULL){
      printf("%s", buf);       
    }                              

    for(j = 0; j < MAX_NUMS; j++){      
      If(fscanf(pt, "%d", &array[a]) != 1);
        Break;

    For(a = n; a--> 0;){
      Printf("%d",  array[a]);
   }

      fclose(pt);
      retuern 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read one number *as a number* at a time into an array, and then loop from the highest element to the lowest?

Answer (score 2):

Use `while(fscanf("%d", &n)){ a[i++] = n; }` initiate `i` with `0` before and declare `a` as an integer array. Later while printing, printing it in reverse order. It is not possible to read from reverse order, though you can go to the end of the file using `fseek()`.

Comment: `while(fscanf("%d", &n))` -> `while(fscanf("%d", &n) == 1)`.  Also check `i` vs the size of the array.

Comment: why don't you write a `main` function with this loop?

Comment: @chqrlie thank you your advice.  I have my main function with command line args at the top of my code.  Are you suggesting more than one function in he program?  Sorry if thats a dumb question, im just a bit confused.  Also, do I need to declare 'n' as a variable?

Comment: @Kaz: sorry for the misunderstanding, I was commenting Mustakimur's post, where he did not write a full program. You would need to declare `int n ;int i = 0; int a[MAX_NUMBERS];` and define `MAX_NUMBERS` to the maximum number of lines you want to handle.

Comment: To me, it's best practice to give people concept than writing their code, so why I am not willing to.

Comment: @MustakimurRahman: I agree with you in general, but there is pedagogical value in giving both. Learn by example, **and** trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code:

- the stream type is spelled `FILE`.
- you do not return from the `main()` function in case of errors.  The program keeps going and you have undefined behavior.
- there is a missing argument in the first `printf()`.
- there is a typo on the `return` statement.

You could define the maximum number of numbers to handle, define an array for the numbers and use a loop index to store the numbers and later print them in reverse order.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUMBERS  1000

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int array[MAX_NUMBERS];
    int i, n;
    FILE *pt;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage %s <files..>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((pt = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open %s for reading.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    for (n = 0; n < MAX_NUMBERS; n++) {
        if (fscanf(pt, "%d", &array[n]) != 1)
            break;
    }

    for (i = n; i-- > 0;) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }

    fclose(pt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: again thank you for the help.  Sorry for the typos, I just need to take a breath and chill out instead of rushing through it all.

Comment: @Kaz: Take my remarks one at a time, look at your source code to see what I am talking about and look at the above code to see how it can be solved.  One learns to walk one step at a time. And believe me, it feels good to keep learning new things everyday.

Comment: i will for sure.  So please tell me what you think.  So i added in your code under my while(fgets statement from my source code, removed my const int MAX 1000 and replaced it with a #define MAX_NUMBERS 1000. But again it just prints out my file in the same order.  Shouldnt i be using my while(fgets to open the file then use the for loops in reverse the text?

Comment: @Kaz: does my code perform the required task?  If it does, you should compare line by line what in your modified version behaves differently.

Comment: it does not perform the task, when i pipe it to my testfile it does not print anything, thats why I thought maybe I had back in my while(fgets statement.  I have edited my source code but again just getting the file to open, it does not reverse it.

Comment: @Kaz: I am confused: what do you mean by *when i pipe it to my testfile it does not print anything,* There is no pipe involved here. The program opens a file whose name is passed on the command line. If the name contains spaces, it must be quoted on the command line.  If the file contains characters that cannot be converted to an integer, `fscanf()` will fail and return a short count, which is dealt with in the code silently, you might add an error message to make this failure more explicit.  Can you post the actual contents of the file?